# How to make Redirection PHP

Tags: php, mysql, redirect

I am attempted to check the database for a varchar "race" and if it's null redirect to a page. this is my code, ive made sure that the var is null yet it does nothing even upon reloading
how do i make php redirect

```
    <?php
    $check_bone_query = mysql_query("SELECT bone FROM users WHERE name = '".$user->name."'");
    {
    if($check_bone_query == NULL){
    header('Location: /bone');
    }  
`   }  
    ?>
```

Comment: make sure it's the only header sent. Add `die;` after the header call.

Comment: How do I [`mysql_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_assoc)?

Comment: @Jocelyn We've seen that in this case the problem is not the redirect, but the fact that the redirect don't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are not fetching any records so maybe use `mysql_fetch_assoc` first?

```
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($check_bone_query);
if (is_null($row)) { //or use empty()
  header('Location: /bone'); exit;
}
```

P.S. get rid of `MySQL_.*` functions use **PDO** or **MySQLi**

Comment: In some rare case not doing the `exit;` after a php redirect would close the browser. Yep... I already saw this. Many times.

Answer (score 0):

Did you executed the header statement before anything was loaded on the page (html code or a echo), sinse you cannot use header() if you already made somthing in the body of the response

so:

```
<html>
 some html
</html>
<?php header(location: 'your new location'); ?>
```

will not work
but:

```
 <?php header(location: 'your new location'); ?>
 <html>
  some html
 </html>
```

will

Comment: may I ask what i did wrong with my answer?
Since if i did somthing worng i would like to know how to do it right the next time

Comment: i didn't downvote it, but if you dealing with a strictly php document, the header line doesn't have to be the first line. i use it inside if/else statements sometimes

Comment: but isn't it true that when you echo somthing before the header() call that it wont work eather?

Comment: right, you won't see the echo, but the redirect will still work

Comment: Then i will edit this

Comment: What he's explaining makes sense and is true. upvoted.